# To-do list application inside Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

Are there any decent to-do list extensions for VS 2010?  I like using the ReSharper To-do Explorer and comment regexes, but for some reminders/tasks etc. I don't want to have to add a comment to code, especially if the task is general and not specific to any one piece of code.  The VS 2010 Task List is very primitive and clunky for other tasks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is any good but I am looking for something similar and found this:

http://www.tasktop.com/products/visual-studio

I also tried this - the developer suggests it will work with VS2010 but I could not get it to work with VS2010 Premium

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1160239-a1ce-426e-9f01-0e4282fd7acb

Maybe you would have more luck

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio will actually allow you to just add new items to the "Task List" pane. You don't have to add a comment that clutters up your code. To do this:

1. Make sure that the Task List is displaying "User Tasks" by choosing it from the drop-down box.
2. Click the little clipboard-with-a-checkmark icon to add a new task.
3. A new item will be added to the list box below; just type your task or comment.

   [image]

Comment: thanks, but in my question I voice my opinion that the Task List is 'primitive and clunky'.  I am of this opinion because it provides precious little in the way of task management w.r.t. categorising, grouping, filtering, etc.

Comment: +1 Also you can select Comments from the dropdown in order to view todos in the form of `TODO: We need to fix this ugly piece of code`

Comment: Did I get this right, that only Ultimate version of Visual studio can support todolist comments?

Comment: @Johnny_D No, that is not correct. It is supported by all versions.